# I can not connect intenet through dongle

Tags: 12.04, internet, mobile-broadband

I am using vodafone dongle but when I am using it ,it is detected inside computerwhile connecting take long time  but can not connect to internet

Comment: Please give more information. Have you installed its software properly. And what does it means it's not detected then how are you trying to connect it if its not able to detect by your system?

Comment: i have not installed software any...It is detected in mobile broadband but can not connect to intenet.

Comment: Try to google for its software for linux, or try to run its exe file using wine.

Comment: there is not any sofware if you know then tell me

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check the operating system you are on. check if the dongle is configured for windows or *nix systems. also, check if you are running software for unix, it has sufficient permissions. if the gui for the software pops up on screen, you might want to check the settings for the particular dongle.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 it it mentioned in tag...I don't have software for dongle to run into ubuntu...yes it has exe file which runs into windows